# How can I disable case sensitivity of MySQL on a Linux based Hosting Server?

Tags: mysql, linux, hosting, cpanel

I have developed an web Application on windows environment but now i need to run it in a Linux based shared Hosting Server. Is there a way I can override my.cnf file with my cPanel or make mysql case insensitive by any other means?

Comment: Nope, probably not without root access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to make your identifiers (column, table, view, and other names)  case insensitive on your Linux shared hosting server.  There's a system variable called [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)  which, when set to the value `1`, treats all identifiers as if they were lower case. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Unfortunately, this system variable is not dynamic. It must be set when the MySQL server is started. So, you asked:

> Is there a way I can override my.cnf file with my cPanel

and the answer is, sad to say, **No.**

Maybe you can get your hosting provider to do this for you. If not, you have some programming work ahead of you to normalize your identifier case names.